# Best way to implement an atomic counter in map in Go

Tags: go, concurrency, atomic

I would like to implement an atomic counter in a map (`map[string]int64`), how can it be implemented in Go? First, I cannot just use int64 as a key, because I can't take address of this value in map for `atomic.AddInt64` func, because maps are not addressable. Second, when using *int64 as value, I must somehow preinitialize int value for the pointer, but initialization on `if _, ok := myMap[key]; !ok { myMap[key] = ... }` won't work, because it will not be atomic, and therefore will require a lock.

Comment: Will the set of keys in the map be dynamically (ie: concurrently) changed? If so, you need to lock the map anyway, so may as well use that lock to protect the counters.

Comment: @PaulHankin you are quite right about locks on key set change, but I'd like to differentiate between these counter updating and entry creating operations, because the latter happens rarely, and It's ok to put a lock and create an entry if key is not found. But for coutner update operations, I just want to read the map and update the referenced int64 value and not use locks. I'm looking for a way of doing it, but seems like there are no options

Answer (score 2):

`sync.Map` has the exact method for your use case, that is `(*sync.Map).LoadOrStore`, which will load an existing value if is able to, and store the given value into the map otherwise.

```
func UpdateCounter(counters *sync.Map, key string) {
    val, _ := counters.LoadOrStore(key, new(int64))
    ptr := val.(*int64)
    atomic.AddInt64(ptr, 1)
}
```

This is done in 2 steps:

- The first one is to canonicalise the entry. i.e. obtain the same entry for the same key regardless of execution order. `(*sync.Map).LoadOrStore` ensures that by atomically looking up the map, putting the entry if absent, or getting the entry from the map otherwise.
- The second step is to increment the counter after obtaining the canonical entry. Since all lookups on the same key return the same entry, this step is trivial.

Comment: You could insert a `1` (instead of `0` like you're doing now) if the key didn't previously exist, so you can skip the `atomic.AddInt64` in that case.  The 2nd return value is a boolean status that's false when it had to store instead of loading an already-present value.  The branch should predict well since `LoadOrStore` probably had to branch on the same condition, and global history or IT-TAGE branch predictors do well with correlated branches.  And atomic RMWs are slow enough, especially on x86-64 where they're necessarily full memory barriers, that it's worth branching to avoid one.

Answer (score 0):

Golang has a synced map in the sync package as documented [here](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#Map), it says that:

> when multiple goroutines read, write, and overwrite entries for disjoint sets of keys.

Which seems to be your use-case, and it says it is better than a map with a mutex.

Answer (score -1):

I think LoadOrStore won't be helping here as you're trying to make an atomic  **transaction** for the read and write (increment) operations.
It will be better to use a map of locks for each entry you're trying to update:

```
urlCache = expiringmap.New[string, int](config.ConfigFile.Ttl)
enrtyLock, _ := r.urlCacheLocks.Get(url)
enrtyLock.Lock()
//your get and set transaction here//
enrtyLock.Unlock()
```

Comment: `LoadOrStore` is not to perform any transaction, it is to canonicalise the entries, i.e. for any order of executions, the end result is that all lookups on the same key would result in the same value. The transaction is done by `atomic.AddInt64` after you have the canonical entry.